Como transformar un string en un DateTime
 
Estoy intentando modificar un registro de la base de datos, el registro me trae la fecha con el formato dd/MM/yyyy HHmmss según entiendo, pero en la base de datos SQL viendo el registro aparece solo yyyy-MM-dd
De esta manera yo intento pasar el String a un Date Time pero me tira el error: System.FormatException: 'No se puede reconocer la cadena como valor Date Time válido.' Y la verdad no se donde esta el error
Realmente no se si el problema estará en el formato de la base de datos o en la clase que yo estoy tratando de modificar, es la primera vez que hago una pregunta asi que estoy perdido de si lo hice bien

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! "pero en la base de datos SQL viendo el registro aparece solo yyyy-MM-dd" como se ve, no quiere decir que este exactamente guardada asi.. como te la devuelve la db en tu programa? como es el select? igual, seguro hay un espacio entre la fecha y la hora...

Te das cuenta de que el formato que aparece en la primera imagen en ningún caso coincide con el formato ingresado en la segunda imagen?

¿Qué DBMS usas? ¿Que es el tipo de datos de tu columna que contiena las fechas?

Prueba a usar el string "yyyy-MM-dd" como segundo parámetro de la función Parse. Hazte un favor, imprime el string FechaNacim y muéstranos lo que obtienes.

Por favor no publiques código o mensajes de error/trazas de pila en imágenes, publica directamente el texto del código, el texto de los errores y los stack traces. Esto hace que sea menos complicado, para quien quiera ayudarte, investigar sobre el tema y hacer sus propias pruebas/adaptaciones al código, al escribir una respuesta y de esa forma aumenta tus posibilidades de encontrar la ayuda que buscas. Un saludo.
